# How to find the solution space (x,y,z) for a function f(x,y,z)=0 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a function, dependant on a vector k=(x,y,z) and a function f(x,y,z)=0, I would like to find the solution space for (x,y,z).

Can this even be done analytically in matlab? I imagine it can be done numerically because my initial thought was to plot the surface created by this function, however this is of no use to me as I have 9 other constants in my equation with no numerical value assigned to them. Many thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: This is for a polynomial degree 4.

Comment: This doesn't strike me as a programming problem unless you want to use the symbolic math toolbox.

Comment: @TryHard: How is this not a programming problem?

Comment: as I said, "unless you want to use...". (You explain yourself how you cannot see a numerical solution)

Comment: @TryHard: If it's possible in mupad why not use MATLAB? Mupad is inferior to MATLAB.

Answer (score 3):

There are no generic, analytical solvers for given function `f(x,y,z)` neither in matlab, nor in any other language. If such solution would exist, the [Riemann hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis) (and dozens others) would be solved ;)

For simple problems you could use `symbolic math toolbox` and a `solve` function:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html

And obbiously there are numerical solvers, which you can use like `vpasolve` and others
http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpasolve.html

Comment: Hahaha.. I suspected as much. A rather naive question really. Probably should have specified it's only a polynomial, just very long, thought it was worth a shot!

Comment: for polynomials, `solve` should be enough. Although it depends on their degree as in general higher degree polynomial do not have closed form analytical solutions.

Comment: Well the issue is I want to solve for x,y and z simultaneously. I'm probably being very stupid but I can't seem to find where it says that!